# Adding a Heroku collaborator for dummies?

Tags: heroku

I'm developing an app for a client and together we agreed to try Heroku, though neither of us has any experience with it. The client will be in control and will add me as a collaborator. The instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing seem pretty simple... except they don't seem to work.

I made an account and so did the client. The client ran the following:

```
heroku apps:create appname
heroku sharing:add myemail@gmail -app appname
```

The client says both of these actions reported success, but I haven't received an e-mail inviting me to collaborate on the app. Presumably some additional steps are required to get things going before collaborators can be added?

Can anyone explain what else we need to do? Alternately, I understand it's possible to transfer ownership of an app, would it be easier for me to create it and then transfer ownership to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify if the collaborator was added from the web UI on heroku.com - go to the 'My Apps' page, find the app and click on the collaborators icon and you should see your new collaborator listed. It's also possible to invite people directly from this page.

Our typical workflow is to build a site for the client in an app in our account and then transfer ownership of the application to the client for golive so they become responsible for billing and such like.

In order to be able to transfer the account, the person who you are transferring to needs to be a collaborator on the application.

Comment: We found the mistake we were making in doing it through the command line, but it's nice to know there's a GUI way to do it which avoids all that. Creating the app myself and then transferring control when it goes live seems like a much easier way to do things in the future, so thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue. We needed another dash in front of app in the add collaborator command; it should have been:

```
heroku sharing:add myemail@gmail --app appname
```

Comment: ha, I thought that was a typo when you posted the question so just overlooked it. Glad you're sorted though.